# Command \mybox already defined

Tags: macros, tcolorbox, fancybox

The following code fails with the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \mybox already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.



 \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
    colback=bg,
    colframe=blue!75!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=blue!75!black,
    colbacktitle=bg,
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-1.2mm, xshift=2mm},
  title=#2,
  #1}

%--------------------

\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{
\setlength{\fboxsep}{7pt}
\begin{center}
\shadowbox{#1}
\end{center}}

%--------------------
```

Could you please help me

Comment: You can have both a tcolorbox mybox and a command \mybox. Choose another name.

Comment: Please help me because I'm beginer

Comment: you just need to call it something else so change `\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{`  to `\newcommand{\anythingbutnotmybox}[1]{`

Comment: Sorry I meant "you can't" not "you can".

Comment: In case you weren't aware, and you are confused why `\mybox` is already defined: When you write `\begin{mybox}` LaTeX translates that into `\mybox` with some checking around it. Therefore, when you created the environment `mybox` as a new tcolorbox, internally, that defined the command `\mybox` :)

Comment: Try to develop a naming protocol, like adding your initials in upper case to everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just replace \mybox by for example \cadre  us follows:

```
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

    \newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
    colback=bg,
    colframe=blue!75!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=blue!75!black,
    colbacktitle=bg,
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-1.2mm, xshift=2mm},
  title=#2,
  #1}

%--------------------

\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
\newcommand{\cadre}[1]{
\setlength{\fboxsep}{7pt}
\begin{center}
\shadowbox{#1}
\end{center}}

%--------------------
```